# Which files are included in APK file

Tags: android, apk

I have a lot of unused images in my android app. Those images are placed in separate folder in project root directory. They are not being used anywhere in a project, but I need to keep them.

My concern is that will these unused images be included in the apk file? Since there are a lot of them and increase the size of apk file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Files stored in the root directory (including custom subdirectories) are *not* included in the APK.  It is very common practice to have your own files needed for the project in the project root.  For example, a  source license file, a to-do list, a directory with high-resolution images that you create distributed images out of, etc.

Android uses these subdirectories with special meaning:

- src/
- res/
- assets/
- libs/
- gen/
- bin/

Using a subdirectory name other than those, Android will ignore your files.

Comment: Thanks, as perfectly composed answer as it can be.

Answer (score 2):

Confirm by your self: create the apk and change the extension to zip and extract that.
You can use an apk optimizer like progaurd and more for same.

Answer (score 1):

addon to @Darshan-JosiahBarber s excellent answer

With android-studio-0.5.8, gradle-1.11 and android-tools.0.9.+ you can also have a folder

- `resources`

for files to be copied relative to the root of the android apk.

Example:

- project file res/some/dir/file.txt will be copied to apk /res/some/dir/file.txt
- project file assets/some/dir/file.txt will be copied to apk /assets/some/dir/file.txt
- project file resources/some/dir/file.txt will be copied to apk /some/dir/file.txt

This folder `resources` is necessary if you want to include `*.properties` files used by crossplatform libs like ical4j.