# Room - Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I am using Android Database Component Room

I've configured everything, but when I compile, Android Studio gives me this warning:

> Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so
>   we cannot export the schema. You can either provide
>   `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set
>   exportSchema to false.

As I understand it is the location where DB file will be located

How can it affect my app? What is the best practice here? Should I use the default location (`false` value)?

Answer (score 547, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Database#exportSchema()):

> You can set annotation processor argument (room.schemaLocation) to tell Room to export the schema into a folder. Even though it is not mandatory, it is a good practice to have version history in your codebase and you should commit that file into your version control system (but don't ship it with your app!).

So if you don't need to check the schema and you want to get rid of the warning, just add `exportSchema = false` to your `RoomDatabase`, as follows.

```
@Database(entities = { YourEntity.class }, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
   //...
}
```

If you follow @mikejonesguy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424908/1363731) below, you will follow the good practice mentioned in the docs.
Basically you will get a `.json` file in your `../app/schemas/` folder, which looks something like this:

```json
{
  "formatVersion": 1,
  "database": {
    "version": 1,
    "identityHash": "53db508c5248423325bd5393a1c88c03",
    "entities": [
      {
        "tableName": "sms_table",
        "createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `message` TEXT, `date` INTEGER, `client_id` INTEGER)",
        "fields": [
          {
            "fieldPath": "id",
            "columnName": "id",
            "affinity": "INTEGER"
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "message",
            "columnName": "message",
            "affinity": "TEXT"
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "date",
            "columnName": "date",
            "affinity": "INTEGER"
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "clientId",
            "columnName": "client_id",
            "affinity": "INTEGER"
          }
        ],
        "primaryKey": {
          "columnNames": [
            "id"
          ],
          "autoGenerate": true
        },
        "indices": [],
        "foreignKeys": []
      }
    ],
    "setupQueries": [
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)",
      "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, \"53db508c5248423325bd5393a1c88c03\")"
    ]
  }
}
```

If my understanding is correct, you will get such a file with every database version update, so that you can easily follow the history of your db.

Comment: I ran into this same error but it was due to adding a constructor to my Entity. Simply add '@Ignore' to any constructor that errors and ad a new blank constructor.

Comment: What does it really mean "Don't ship with your app" ? It will included in APK ?

Comment: Yes, I got a similar json file with all the details.

Comment: If follow "Don't ship with your app", should I remove JSON files before generating APK?

Comment: "Don't ship with your app" means "Don't set schemaLocation to like 'app/res/raw'. Set the schemaLocation to a directory not included in the APK."

Comment: @galcyurio $projectDir/schemas is a directory out of the APK, right? I have explored the generated APK and I don't see it over there. Although I see /res (which accounts for app/src/main/res) for example.

Comment: @xarlymg89 Were you able to confirm that `$projectDir/schemas` is _NOT_ included in the APK? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10927390/11566289), custom subdirectories are not.

Comment: @glucaio I explored the APK (and the App bundle too) and didn't find it. So I believe we're safe.

Comment: How do we keep this out of a release APK?

Comment: use `exportSchema = false` and it will not be generated

Comment: The link in the answer points to the deprecated documentation of android.arch package. The corresponding documentation in androidx.* is: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Database#exportSchema()

Answer (score 592):

In the `build.gradle` file for your app module, add this to the `defaultConfig` section (under the `android` section). This will write out the schema to a `schemas` subfolder of your project folder.

```
javaCompileOptions {
    annotationProcessorOptions {
        arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
// ...

android {
    
    // ... (compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, etc)

    defaultConfig {

        // ... (applicationId, miSdkVersion, etc)
        
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
   
    // ... (buildTypes, compileOptions, etc)

}

// ...
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering, this exact approach also works for Kotlin when using *kapt*

Comment: Should we gitignore the json file generated in the `app/schemas` directory by this operation. And I heard we should put the schema into a directory that is not included in the `apk`. How can we do that?

Comment: @ravi the generated schema file(s) should be stored in version control as this is used by Room to detect changes and help ensure if the database changes you update the database version and create a migration plan

Comment: Does this configuration affect to the release version? I mean, when I export the project to a release app.

Comment: If this solution results in **ERROR: Could not find method annotationProcessorOptions() for arguments**, check out Luna's answer, below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54366985/1617737

Comment: Desse jeito funcionou, a solução anterior do @DoruChidean não funcionou no meu cenário.

Comment: use `arguument +=` so it does not mess with your DI libraries like Hilt.(see this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/62891182/5780236)

Comment: @mikejonesguy an edit with the information in these comments would be super helpful. Knowing it works with kapt - I missed that and also went down a rabbit hole with the Hilt problem mentioned by Ahmad.

Comment: @ChantellOsejo updated just now. Changed "arguments = ..." to "arguments += ...".

Comment: I added the javaCompileOptions to my gradle file but still get the warning. What am I missing?

Comment: this should be upvoted for good reasons

Comment: I'm getting "Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match." on the `+=` and "Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)" for the `: "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]`

Answer (score 342):

Kotlin? Here we go:

```
android {

    // ... (compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, etc)

    defaultConfig {

        // ... (applicationId, miSdkVersion, etc)

        kapt {
            arguments {
                arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        // ... (buildTypes, compileOptions, etc)
    }
}

//...
```

Don't forget about plugin:

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

For more information about kotlin annotation processor please visit: 
[Kotlin docs](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html)

Comment: I got a `> No signature of method: build_xyz.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_xyz$_run_closure1) values: [build_xyz$_run_closure1@719007a9]` where `xyz` is a long random string... is it a bug?

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schema) is probably a better option

Comment: @mikejonesguy's answer above worked for me.

Comment: Same issue here with the missing signature method.

Comment: When using javaCompileOptions as suggested by other answers I saw an error "Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_....android() is applicable for argument types... ". It looks like javaCompileOptions might have been deprecated. I'm using AGP v7.0.2. I needed to use kapt{} instead to set the argument as described by Ivanov (I used it within android{} and the schema was output).

Comment: When using this solution, i had to move the DB definition as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68649685/2664521
Using https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#export-schema prevented the need of moving the file

Answer (score 87):

For Kotlin KSP:

```
ksp {
    arg('room.schemaLocation', "$projectDir/schemas")
}
```

(it's Groovy DSL, in Kotlin DSL use double quotes)

Comment: You can paste this wherever you want to the `build.gradle (:app)`.

Comment: where to paste this guys?

Comment: @josh you can paste in your defaultConfig tag in build.gradle (:app)

Comment: I was told to turn the single quotes into double quotes, but otherwise this worked for me!

Comment: @PaulStephenson Single quotes are used in Groovy DSL. In Kotlin DSL you should use double quotes.

Answer (score 18):

Above answers are correct. This version is easy to follow:

Because "Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor", So we need to provide the directory for schema export:

> Step [1] In your file which extends the RoomDatabase, change the line to:

```
`@Database(entities = ???.class,version = 1, exportSchema = true)`
```

Or

```
`@Database(entities = ???.class,version = 1)`
```

(because the default value is always true)

> Step [2] In your build.gradle(project:????) file, inside the **defaultConfig{ }** (which is inside **android{ }** big section), add the **javaCompileOptions{ }** section, it will be like:

```
         android{
                defaultConfig{
                      //javaComplieOptions SECTION
                      javaCompileOptions {
                            annotationProcessorOptions {
                                     arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
                            }
                       }
                      //Other SECTION
                      ...
                }
         }
```

**$projectDir**:is a variable name, you cannot change it. it will get your own project directory

**schemas**:is a string, you can change it to any you like. For example:
`"$projectDir/MyOwnSchemas".toString()`

Comment: in step[2], are you sure it's the `build.gradle(project:????)` and not `build.gradle(app:????)`?

Answer (score 16):

@mikejonesguy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424908/4325011) is perfect, just in case you plan to test room migrations (recommended), add the schema location to the source sets.

> In your build.gradle file you specify a folder to place these
>   generated schema JSON files. As you update your schema, you’ll end up
>   with several JSON files, one for every version. Make sure you commit
>   every generated file to source control. The next time you increase
>   your version number again, Room will be able to use the JSON file for
>   testing.
>
> - Florina Muntenescu ([source](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/testing-room-migrations-be93cdb0d975))

**build.gradle**

```
android {

    // [...]

    defaultConfig {

        // [...]

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    // add the schema location to the source sets
    // used by Room, to test migrations
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: this causes some conflicts with `Hilt`, just replace the `arguments =` with `arguments +=`

Answer (score 7):

```js
kapt {
  arguments {
    arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I use `.kts` Gradle files (Kotlin Gradle DSL) and the `kotlin-kapt` plugin but I still get a script compilation error when I use Ivanov Maksim's answer.

```
Unresolved reference: kapt
```

For me this was the only thing which worked:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = mapOf("room.schemaLocation" to "$projectDir/schemas")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is working for me either. I am using Kotlin.

Comment: How does this answer work? arguments is a MutableMap, `val arguments: MutableMap<String, String>` and gives compile error when you try to assign anything, and adding with `arguments["room.schemaLocation"] ="$projectDir/schemas"`does not work for me. Other answer also does not work.

Answer (score 5):

**Kotlin** way according to [official document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#compiler-options):

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments += mapOf(
                "room.schemaLocation" to "$projectDir/schemas",
                "room.incremental" to "true",
                "room.expandProjection" to "true"
            )
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just posting what worked for me using **`Kotlin DSL`**

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId = ""
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        
        //add this in the build.gradle.kts(app) file
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments["room.schemaLocation"] =
                    "$projectDir/schemas"
            }
        }
    }
```

For this to work you also need to set `exportSchema` to `true`

```
@Database(entities = [Entity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = true)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ScoresDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val dao: ScoresDAO
}
```

To confirm it worked, you should see the newly created ***schemas*** directory off the module root directory with the next build as illustrated below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using room with **ksp** add this in your **app-module-build**

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    /**
     * Set the Room database schema export location for debug build to inspect the database
     */
    ksp {
        arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If like me you recently moved certain classes to different packages ect. and you use android navigation. Make sure to change the argType to you match you new package address.
from:

```
app:argType="com.example.app.old.Item"
```

to:

```
app:argType="com.example.app.new.Item"
```

Comment: So weird, mine was because of the import statement in DataBinding XML

Answer (score 1):

```
// For javac or KAPT, configure using android DSL:
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    javaCompileOptions {
      annotationProcessorOptions {
        compilerArgumentProviders(
          RoomSchemaArgProvider(File(projectDir, "schemas"))
        )
      }
    }
  }
}

// For KSP, configure using KSP extension:
ksp {
  arg(RoomSchemaArgProvider(File(projectDir, "schemas")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't add your room class to child `RoomDatabase` child class in `@Database(entities = {your_classes})`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using room with ksp in the module build you have to define RoomSchemaArgProvider

```
class RoomSchemaArgProvider(
    @get:InputDirectory
    @get:PathSensitive(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)
    val schemaDir: File
) : CommandLineArgumentProvider {

    override fun asArguments(): Iterable<String> {
        // Note: If you're using KSP, change the line below to return
         return listOf("room.schemaLocation=${schemaDir.path}")
//        return listOf("-Aroom.schemaLocation=${schemaDir.path}")
    }
}

android {


    // For KSP, configure using KSP extension:
    ksp {
        arg(RoomSchemaArgProvider(File(projectDir, "schemas")))
    }
}
```

And then make sure that you have directory in app/schemas
Do not know why it was not created automatically in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using KSP, you can add the required argument like this:

```
android {
    // Your existing android configuration here...

    // KSP-specific configuration
    ksp {
        arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
}
```