# Android room persistent: AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-room

My app database class

```
@Database(entities = {Detail.class}, version = Constant.DATABASE_VERSION)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract FavoritesDao favoritesDao();

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, Constant.DATABASE).allowMainThreadQueries().build();

                    //Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),AppDatabase.class).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }
}
```

Gradle lib:

```
 compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:+"   
 annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:+"
```

And when i ask for instance it will give this error,  AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
in my application class

```
public class APp extends Application {

    private boolean appRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(this); //--AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

    }   

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the proper logcat error, you are getting?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

Comment: Have you provided the room schema location in gradle?

Comment: @pratikdeshai Did you get any solution to this issue? I'm also having the same problem.

Comment: In my case I removed the kotlin plugin to get it fixed.
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

Answer (score 556, accepted):

For those working with **Kotlin**, try changing `annotationProcessor` to `kapt` in the apps `build.gradle`

for example:

```
// Extensions = ViewModel + LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
// Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

also remember to  add this plugin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

to the top of the app level build.gradle file and do a clean and rebuild (according to https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#6)

> In Android Studio, if you get errors when you paste code or during the build process, select Build >Clean Project. Then select Build > Rebuild Project, and then build again.

---

## UPDATE

If you have migrated to androidx

```
def room_version = "2.3.0" // check latest version from docs

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

## UPDATE 2 (since July 2021)

```
def room_version = "2.3.0" // check latest version from docs

implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

## UPDATE 3 (since October 2023)

For those working with Kotlin and Android Room, consider using KSP (Kotlin Symbol Processing) instead of KAPT (Kotlin Annotation Processing Tool) for Room annotations. KSP is aprox 2x faster than KAPT, making your build process more efficient.

```
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
```

Don't forget to add ksp plugin

```
id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
```

For more details and the latest updates on using KSP, refer to the official Android documentation: *https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just moving to Kotlin and all my test cases started failing. Was banging my head. Then I accidentally saw this comment. Saved my day.

Comment: Also need to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to the top of the app level `build.gradle` file

Comment: This saved me....I think Google should work more on showing proper error...I had kapt call but I didnt add apply kapt-plugin

Comment: Was stuck since yesterday. thanks a lot. I don't understand why don't google people mention this in the documentation.

Comment: You're the GOAT saved me with that quick gradle fix

Comment: Works for me but I'd love to understand why, could you elaborate?

Comment: It now has changed to `implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"`

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Comment: it worked for me

Comment: I tried to add that line of ksp
and when I try to sync, I get the error:

Plugin [id: 'com.google.devtools.ksp'] was not found in any of the following source

Comment: @dexter00x https://stackoverflow.com/a/77361050/619673

Answer (score 95):

Just use

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

in app build.gradle

And keep both in dependencies

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

**EDIT**

In newer version don't need to add both dependencies at a time 
Just use, hope it will work.

```
kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 27):

I had this error when I missed

```
@Database(entity="{<model.class>})
```

Ensure that the entity model specified in the annotation above refers to the particular model class and also ensure that the necessary annotation:

```
@Entity(tableName = "<table_name>" ...)
```

is properly defined and you'd be good

Comment: For clarity, this goes immediately above the DB class definition. It appears to have fixed my problem - thanks!

Comment: make sure you don't have empty constructors (constructor(){}) in your entities https://stackoverflow.com/a/60494924/6148931

Comment: I had this problem and changing the build.gradle as the accepted answer did not solve the problem. Adding this annotation solved the problem, but in [the tutorial I was following](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#groovy), the "user" class has only `@Entity`, not `@Entity(tablename="table name" )`. If this is required, why does the tutorial lack this annotation?

Answer (score 23):

if you are using kotlin classes to implement database then 
use

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

in your gradle file, it will work.

Comment: This works on Android Studio 3.5 (however the current room compiler version is 2.1.0)

Comment: I think most of the people were not using androidx library in whole project... that why I suggested 1.1.1... I myself faced compilation issues and felt safe with minimal changes using older version.

Answer (score 15):

**For Kotlin Developers**

Use this:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

And add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to the top of the app level `build.gradle`.

**For Java Developers**

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

Comment: Different answers!

Comment: How come this is different dude?

Comment: it's the solution , it helped me to get over the error

Answer (score 13):

Agreed with the above answers

The solution is as below. Change annotationProcessor to kapt as below

```
// annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `kotlin`, add kotlin annotation processor plugin to app level `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt"
}
```

Also remove `annotationProcessor` and replace it with `kapt`

- Instead of

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

- Use

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

The `annotationProcessor` only works in java environment. The `kapt` takes care of both java and kotlin. If something wrong with your implementation, those plugins will show them at the compile time.

Comment: tried adding `plugins {...}` and replacing `kapt` with `annotationProcessor` but separately, thank you very much for answering..

Answer (score 11):

It is not just about updating your dependencies. Make sure all your Room dependencies have the same version.

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0-alpha2'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-alpha2'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-alpha2"
```

In the sample snippet above, all my Room dependencies have the same version `1.1.0-alpha2`

Answer (score 9):

I meet with the problem, because I forget `@Dao` annotation

```
@Dao
public interface SearchHistoryDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM search_history")
    List<SearchHistory> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(SearchHistory... histories);

    @Delete()
    void delete(SearchHistory history);
}
```

[Room Official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)

Comment: I forgot it too. Thank you :) But still crashh :(

Comment: Fix by adding kapt

Answer (score 9):

make sure to add correct dependency for room in build.gradle

```
ext {
   roomVersion = '2.1.0-alpha06'
}

// Room components
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

And below line at the top-

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 8):

I met this problem because I have forgotten the apt dependences

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$archRoomVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$archRoomVersion"
```

after added the annotationProcessor, and rebuild it, the problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem. Implemented the few classes and interface as officially told in a new example project created by Android Studio:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

All mentioned solutions above did not help, the necessary _Impl files according to my database class were not generated by Room. Finally executing gradle clean build in terminal gave me the hint that lead to the solution:

"warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false."

I added the parameter exportSchema = false in the database class

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(User::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

And then it worked, found these two generated files in the app module under generatedJava:

- AppDatabase_Impl
- UserDao_Impl

I don't understand this behaviour as the parameter is said to be optional, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645943/3258117

Comment: Running ./gradlew clean build from the terminal was the key.
For me I got this message:
app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1' and apply the kapt plugin: "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'".

Comment: Ah yes, executing the tasks in terminal also helped me a lot in the past. The build tools messages in the IDE often "hide" the original error message

Answer (score 7):

The question is pretty old, but I've stumbled on this today and none of the provided answers helped me. Finally I managed to resolve it by noticing that google [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) actually is still adopted to Java and not Kotlin by default, actually they have added a comment which I've ignored

> For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

So, instead of

`annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"`

If you are developing with Kotlin, you should use:

```
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 4):

In my kotlin app, I just added the following line at the top of my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

And the following line in the dependencies section:

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
```

I hope it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following gradle link:

```
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9'
```

You need to create a different singleton class and get the AppDatabase from there like this:

**RoomDB.java**

```
public class RoomDB {

private static RoomDB INSTANCE;

public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE =
                Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, Constant.DATABASE).allowMainThreadQueries().build();

                //Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),AppDatabase.class).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public static void destroyInstance() {
    INSTANCE = null;
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

private boolean appRunning = false;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    RoomDB.getInstance(this); //This will provide AppDatabase Instance
}
```

Comment: i didn't create constructor, i am using directly via static instance.

Comment: I have created a Sample Project for Room Database you can check it here: https://github.com/burhanrashid52/Android-Room-Data-Persistent

Comment: yes i updated but sill same error, AppDatabase_Impl does not exist

Comment: @pratikdeshai: Have you fixed that error ?? I also get same error, get stuck because of this.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was testing the connectivity for room database and I have put the testing class inside the directory which I have created inside the AndroidTest folder. I have moved it out of the custom directory, then it worked pretty well.

Comment: This is my issue too. Any idea why this is happening and how to avoid this? I'd rather prefer not to have a `TestDatabase` in the release code.

Answer (score 3):

The same phenomenon occurred to me.

following

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
```

Adding causes another build error but tracks the cause from the log.

In my case, there was an error in the SQL implementation.
After fixing, the build was successful.

So you may want to check the implementation of the entire room library instead of looking at the crashed locals.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is more around the correct library that is not included in the gradle build. I had a similar issue and added the missing

> testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version

Answer (score 2):

Changing the dependencies in my gradle file did'nt help me in fixing the error.I had missed this Database annotation in class where Room database was initialized which was causing this issue.

> @Database(entities = [UserModel::class], version = 1)

Ensure that the entity model specified in the annotation above refers to the particular model class

Comment: this is what i missed

Answer (score 2):

For me, the Android Studio automatically updated dependencies as soon as you include any of the Room database related imports. But as per https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies you need to update few. Here is how my code-base looks like:

AppDatabase.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = arrayOf(MyEntity::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun myDAO(): MyDAO

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance: AppDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context)= instance ?: synchronized(LOCK){
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it}
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "db-name.db")
            .build()
    }
}
```

Update the build.gradle as specified in one of the answers:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // this goes with other declared plugin at top
dependencies { // add/update the following in dependencies section
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3'
//    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3' // remove this and use the following
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3"

}
```

Sync the gradle and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

**For Kotlin Developers**

---

if you checked Dao and Entity and also used Kapt and there is no problem, I guess there is a problem with your kotlin version if you are using kotlin 1.4 and above.
update Room to last version from this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room).

---

**2.3.0-alpha03** solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Update Answer 2023**

I was facing the same issue and after wasting 10 hours and all the above solutions, the following steps worked.

First I changed my gradle version to the latest i.e

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

TO

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip
```

plus I changed Java version in all modules from

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

TO

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

After That I did clean and Run but had No Luck, Then I added the following dependencies in my gradle file as per someone's answer.

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0-alpha01"
annotationProcessor  "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-alpha01"
kapt  "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-alpha01"
```

It didn't work as well but I found suggestion that latest version of room is available for alpha i.e

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0-alpha01"
annotationProcessor  "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0-alpha01"
kapt  "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0-alpha01"
```

Now after updating that, it started working!

So I suggest that Update your gradle version, Kotlin version, and Java version and use the latest room it will work.
As I am using the multi-module app with Dagger, Many people suggested that add dependencies of Room in the *APP Module* as well, But I found that there is no need of adding Room in *APP Module*, Just add it in the core module where required.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer using ksp. Android developer documentation asserts that kapt is now (May 2023) in maintenance mode. I'm writing a Kotlin app.

Add to your project-level build.gradle:

```
plugins {
...
   id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version "1.8.21-1.0.11" apply false
}
```

Add to your module-level build.gradle:

```
plugins {
...
   id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
}
```

```
android {
...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
                     // was JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = 11
        // was jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    // this may not be necessary but my app has it
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.7'
    }
...
}
```

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(11)
}
```

```
dependencies {
...
    def room_version = "2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

In addition, because I was updating the Java version, I got an error about a `jlink` executable not existing, and solved that by installing the latest JDK on my machine.

> Fedora: `sudo dnf install java-11-openjdk-devel`

> Ubuntu: `sudo apt install default-jdk default-jre`

References:

Google developer documentation on migrating from `kapt` to `ksp`: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp

latest `ksp` release listed here (web search "android latest ksp release"): https://github.com/google/ksp/releases

latest Room release listed here (web search "android latest room release"): https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room

latest `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` release listed here (web search "android latest kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion release"): https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler

Stack Overflow posts about an error I hit along the way which caused me to update the JDK:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kspDebugKotlin'. Unable to build with ksp

'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kspDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

answers found here:

[How to set compileJava' task ( 11) and 'compileKotlin' task (1.8) jvm target compatibility to the same Java version in build.gradle.kts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079963/how-to-set-compilejava-task-11-and-compilekotlin-task-1-8-jvm-target-com)

[Build Error: 'kspDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75650195/build-error-kspdebugkotlin-task-current-target-is-17)

Stack overflow posts about how to fix the error I got ("jlink does not exist") once I'd updated the Java version in build.gradle: [How to fix jlink does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73107234/how-to-fix-jlink-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to missing

`annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:x.x.x"`

I had also missed adding the below annotation in my class

```
@Entity(tableName = "mytablename")
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing works from above answers and I noticed that the issue persists for me when I'm using room version`2.3.0` or `2.4.2`. However, `2.5.0-alpha01` version works well when I applied it.

`build.gradle:app`

```
def roomVersion = '2.5.0-alpha01'
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$roomVersion"
```

Answer (score 1):

check this annotation above class

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Schedule::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
// ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case just by changing `annotationProcessor` to `kapt` on my `room-compiler` dependency, did the work.

Answer (score 1):

As of Jan 2023 - I faced a similar issue after refactoring my code to use ServiceLocator class.

I resolved it by going on a spree of changing room versions. It worked with 2.5.0-alpha02

version_room = "2.5.0-alpha02" <-- build.gradle (project)

```
 //Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$version_room"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$version_room"
// optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$version_room"
implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$version_room")
```

I am running the following on Android Eel 2020.1.1:

version_kotlin = "1.7.21"
version_android_gradle_plugin = "4.0.1"

Comment: It is recommended to use KSP instead of KAPT.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the dependencies I have used to resolve this issue :

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

dependencies {
    //dependencies for room
     implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1")
     kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"
     kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these dependencies in **build.gradle** file

> **implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")**

> **kapt ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1")**

> **implementation ("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")**

Answer (score 0):

Reading the example here:
[Room Example](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-livedata-and-viewmodel-fca5da39e26b)

I fixed this error just using the correct (I guess it is) annotationProcessorFile, as follows:

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:<latest_version>"
```

Also, I upgraded to 2.2.0 either in Room Version as in Lifecycle version.

Once synchronized the graddle, I could start working with Room.

So, Good luck! And let the code be with you!

Answer (score 0):

Not in the case of OP, but this also happens when you mistakenly use **implementation** instead of **annotationProcessor** like this:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:x.x.x"
```

Instead of this:

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:x.x.x"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone out there should make the same mistake as I did, don't call your database class "Database" or you'll get the same error.