# ava.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.bookkeepers.BookViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I am developing a new book android app but app crashes when I am testing the code getting following exceptions from logcat

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.bookkeepers/com.example.bookkeepers.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
>   com.example.bookkeepers.BookViewModel  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2921)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1639) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) Caused
>   by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
>   com.example.bookkeepers.BookViewModel  at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:208)
>   at androidx.l
>
> ifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:135)  at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:103) 
>   at com.example.bookkeepers.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:30) 
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7074)  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7065)  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2796)
>   ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)  at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:200)
>   ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find
>   implementation for com.example.bookkeepers.BookRoomDatabase.
>   BookRoomDatabase_Impl does not exist  at
>   androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:94)  at
>   androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:952)  at
>   com.example.bookkeepers.BookRoomDatabase$Companion.getDatabase(BookRoomDatabase.kt:24)
>   at com.example.bookkeepers.BookViewModel.(BookViewModel.kt:12) 
>   ... 19 more
>
> below my BookViewModel class which extends AndroidViewModel class

```
class BookViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private val bookDao: BookDao

init {
    val bookDb = BookRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application)

    bookDao = bookDb!!.bookDao()
}


fun insert(book: Book) {
    InsertAsyncTask(bookDao).execute(book)
}

companion object {
    private class InsertAsyncTask(private val bookDao: BookDao) :
        AsyncTask<Book, Void, Void>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg books: Book): Void? {
            bookDao.insert(books[0])
            return null
        }

    }
}}
```

below MainActivity.kt
class

```
MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 lateinit var bookViewModel: BookViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        val intent =  Intent(this, NewBookActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_NOTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
   bookViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BookViewModel::class.java)
}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == NEW_NOTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val authorName = data!!.getStringExtra(NewBookActivity.NEW_AUTHOR)
        val bookName = data!!.getStringExtra(NewBookActivity.NEW_BOOK)

        val book = Book(id, authorName, bookName)
        bookViewModel.insert(book)

        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            R.string.saved,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            R.string.not_saved,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }
}

companion object{
    private const val NEW_NOTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1
}}
```

below database class

```
  @Database(entities = [Book::class], version = 1)
 abstract class BookRoomDatabase :RoomDatabase() {


abstract fun bookDao():BookDao


companion object {

    private var bookRoomInstance:BookRoomDatabase? = null
    fun getDatabase(context: Context): BookRoomDatabase? {
        if (bookRoomInstance == null)
            synchronized(BookRoomDatabase::class.java){
                if(bookRoomInstance == null){
                    bookRoomInstance = Room.databaseBuilder<BookRoomDatabase>(context.applicationContext,
                        BookRoomDatabase::class.java, "book_database")
                        .build()
                }
            }
    return bookRoomInstance
    }

}}
```

below dao class

```
@Dao
 interface BookDao {
  @Insert
  fun insert(book: Book)
  }
```

below book entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "books")
class Book(@PrimaryKey val id: String,

       @ColumnInfo(name = "author")
       val author: String,
       val book:String) {
}
```

Comment: I've never used Room but I notice you are trying to instantiate an Abstract class, I don't think that's possible. You should have a subclass of `BookRoomDatabase` that implements the abstract functions. I think that's why you are seeing the crash, because it can't create an instance of the abstract class.

Comment: can you post your Gradle dependencies of the Arch Components?

Comment: @jsmyth886 the abstract keyword is  not a problem but a requirement  in Room  database. Check the docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind it that you are using kotlin and in your app `build.gradle` you should be applying kapt plugin `apply plugin 'kotlin-kapt'` and using `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor`

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"

implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
```

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50487165/4614550

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to instantiate the ViewModel without providing the required arguments `application: Application`.
I posted an answer that solves this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004171/13834895.