# ViewModel has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, viewmodel

I'm trying to make a simple ToDoList application using the recyclerview and the room library. I'm following the android developers codelab on [using room and mvvm architecture](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#14) and I seem to have hit a stump. I have set up every layer of the application but I'm getting an error when trying to instantiate the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) using the ViewModelProvider. Here is the code from my [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) class.

```
class TaskViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private val repository : TaskRepository

val allTasks : LiveData<List<Task>>



init{
    val tasksDao = TaskRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application)!!.taskDao()
    repository = TaskRepository(tasksDao)
    allTasks = repository.allTasks

}

fun saveTask(task : Task) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    repository.saveTask(task)
}
```

}

And here is the code from my MainFragment from which I'm trying to initialize the ViewModel:

```
class MainFragment() : Fragment() {

private lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView
private lateinit var sharedTaskViewModel : TaskViewModel
private lateinit var fab : FloatingActionButton
var tasks = emptyList<Task>()
private lateinit var adapter : MainRecyclerViewAdapter

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    fab = view.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton)
    //Initialize the recyclerview
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.main_recyclerview)
    adapter = MainRecyclerViewAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context)


    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    sharedTaskViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TaskViewModel::class.java)


    fab.setOnClickListener {
        fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.fl_fragment_main, NewTaskFragment())
            commit()
        }
    }

}
```

}

When I run the code I get this message:

```
2020-08-09 11:31:00.734 27860-27860/com.robybp.todolist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.robybp.todolist, PID: 27860
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.robybp.todolist.view_models.TaskViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at com.robybp.todolist.view.fragments.MainFragment.onViewCreated(MainFragment.kt:45)
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.robybp.todolist.view_models.TaskViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
```

Please do forgive me if the question may be "Obslite" but i'm just getting familiar with room and mvvm architecture.
Thank you for understanding.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50487165/9188214

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
sharedTaskViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TaskViewModel::class.java)
```

with

```
sharedTaskViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application)
    .create(TaskViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: hey need help over here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266686/how-do-i-remove-row-from-recyclerview-using-room/63297383?noredirect=1#comment112047918_63297383