# Databinding with Koin and Room

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-databinding, koin

I have the following issue:
I am using Koin for DI and Room for persistence. Now my room dependencies are the following:

```
// Architecture Component - Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

But I get the error described here:
[Android room persistent: AppDatabase_Impl does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665621/android-room-persistent-appdatabase-impl-does-not-exist)

So I changed the annotationProcessor to kapt. But now I get multiple errors in auto-generated from data binding classes which were not there with the annotationProcessor.
For example:

```
app/build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug/out/databinding/FragmentBinding.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
  protected FragmentBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                     ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class FragmentBinding
```

Koin module defintion:

```
val persistenceModule = module {
    single {
        Room.databaseBuilder(androidApplication(), Database::class.java, "database.db")
            .build()
    }
    single { get<Database>().dao() }
}
```

How can this happen?

Comment: I think this shows Databinding error

Comment: I don't think the error has anything to do with room or Koin. Your koin module looks ok.

The error is pointing out to a data binding error on a layout file.

Answer (score 1):

try `single<YourDB>`:

```
val dbModule = module {
    single<FairytaleDB> { Room.databaseBuilder(get(), FairytaleDB::class.java, "Fairytale.db").createFromAsset("ertak.db").build() }
    single { get<FairytaleDB>().getDao() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added **kapt plugin** in your app level `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can provide the dependency of Room through Koin, Below is the code

```
  fun providesDatabase(application: Application):UserDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(application,UserDatabase::class.java,"userdatabase")
            .build()

fun providesDao(db:UserDatabase):UserDao = db.userDao()


val roomModule = module {

    single { providesDatabase(get()) }
    single { providesDao(get()) }
}
```