# Collection contains no element matching the predicate

Tags: android, android-room, kapt

I'm using the Room library, and I'm getting the following error message when I try to build the app:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
```

Here is a more detailed error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I isolated the problem in the code to be somewhere in the following, although I don't know what exactly is throwing this exception:

```
package com.example.pomoplay

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [(Category::class)], version = 1)
abstract class PomoPlayDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun categoryDao(): CategoryDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: PomoPlayDatabase? = null
        internal fun getDatabase(context: Context): PomoPlayDatabase?
        {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(PomoPlayDatabase::class.java) {
                    if (INSTANCE == null) {
                        INSTANCE =
                            Room.databaseBuilder<PomoPlayDatabase>(
                                context.applicationContext,
                                PomoPlayDatabase::class.java,
                                "pomoplay_database").build()
                    }
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }
    }
}
```

**Gradle.build - project**

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
        dependencies {


            classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

**Gradle.build - module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pomoplay"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0'

    //Room Components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3"

    //Testing Components
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Comment: can you share the code file where you are using the collection with predicate?

Comment: @DipankarBaghel I don't know where in the code this refers to.

Comment: @DipankarBaghel I don't think I'm even using a predicate in my code.

Comment: Compile time errors without line number are very irritating. That is where we are thrown in limbo

Answer (score 6):

In my case its happening when or because im trying to make filter by one field that does not exist example

```
class Items(id:Int, name:String, isNew:Boolean)
```

so when I filter a list of "Items" with something like this

```
var list:Arraylist<Items>
list.filter{it->it.isNew}
```

if my backend does not have o retrieve that field "isNew" my code trow my that exceptions, that's was in my case

Answer (score 3):

No need to create separate Data class. Just make sure its `Serializable`

After spending a day for this error, I identified the issue to be presence of an empty constructor in the @Entity class.

```
constructor() {}
```

Its not that always this constructor should be absent. 
I have another @Entity class where it is very much needed or else it fails with this error

```
Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. 
You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
public final class Question implements java.io.Serializable
```

Not understood the reasoning behind it, but must be way of our usage. 
That shouldn't mean Android Studio should go silent on Line number of compilation error. It felt like a mouse trap

Comment: Pointing to proper hint.

Answer (score 2):

To track down the source of the problem, I took out all the files in the project and then put back one file at a time and isolated the problem to the room database class file I mentioned above in my original question. I thought that maybe the `Category::class` attribute in the array of the `@Database` annotation has something wrong with it.

I looked at how I constructed the `Category` class and compared it to how entity classes are constructed in other Android Room projects. Those projects used a Data class for the entities, whereas I used a regular POCO style structure. So, I implemented a Data class instead and now everything is working.

**Category data class:**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "categories_table")
data class Category(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @NonNull @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryId") val id: Int, @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryName") val name: String, @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryDesc") val desc: String)
```