# Filter last element and add to top of list in mutable list kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in Kotlin. I need your help to sort my mutableList in custom data class. I need to find the search element in the list and put into the top of list. Mostly the search element is in the last element. So I don't know how to filter that. Please give me some suggestions how to achieve that. For example

**Data Class**

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) 

data class Item(val gender: Int, val human: List<Human>)

data class Human(val id: Int, val person: List<Person>)
```

I entered some fake data

```
val people = mutableListOf(
        Item(1,
                listOf(
                        Human(
                                1,
                                listOf(
                                        Person("Ragnar", "Lodbrok"),
                                        Person("Bjorn", "Ironside"),
                                        Person("Sweyn", "Forkbeard")
                                )
                        ),
                        Human(
                                2,
                                listOf(
                                        Person("Ragnar", "Lodbrok"),
                                        Person("Bjorn", "Ironside"),
                                        Person("Sweyn", "Forkbeard")
                                )
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

If i want to search **Forkbeard** and want to put in top of list. But i am unable to do this. So please suggest me some good advice.

I tried this but not working

```
people.forEach { people ->
        people.human.forEach { human ->
            human.person.sortedByDescending { person ->
                person.lastName == "Forkbeard"
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting this

```
[Item(gender=1, human=[Human(id=1, person=[Person(firstName=Ragnar, lastName=Lodbrok), Person(firstName=Bjorn, lastName=Ironside), Person(firstName=Sweyn, lastName=Forkbeard)]), Human(id=2, person=[Person(firstName=Ragnar, lastName=Lodbrok), Person(firstName=Bjorn, lastName=Ironside), Person(firstName=Sweyn, lastName=Forkbeard)])])]
```

**Answer**

**I want this**

```
[Item(gender=1, human=[Human(id=1, person=[Person(firstName=Sweyn, lastName=Forkbeard),Person(firstName=Ragnar, lastName=Lodbrok), Person(firstName=Bjorn, lastName=Ironside)]), Human(id=2, person=[Person(firstName=Sweyn, lastName=Forkbeard),Person(firstName=Ragnar, lastName=Lodbrok), Person(firstName=Bjorn, lastName=Ironside)])])]
```

```
[ Sweyn Forkbeard, Ragnar Lodbrok, Bjorn Ironside ]
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a single item from a list, you can use the `first` function:

```
val sweyn: Person = people.first { it.lastName == "Forkbeard" }
```

Then, for adding sweyn at the top:

```
people.remove(sweyn)
people.add(0, sweyn)
```

If you need to constantly do this, maybe you are looking for a [Queue](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Queue)

EDIT:

For the nested human list, you can do the same if you change the `person`'s type to MutableList in the `Human` data class:

```
people.forEach { people ->
    people.human.forEach { human ->
        val sweyn: Person = human.person.first { it.lastName == "Forkbeard" }
        human.person.remove(sweyn)
        human.person.add(0, sweyn)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Is this better in performance when we do in json.. I need to do in big data coming from server..

Comment: @VivekModi I updated my answer. As a side note, you can still do this with a inmutable List, but this will require more work since you will have to copy() the `people` and the `human` objects.

Comment: i am getting the error this. java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710677/collection-contains-no-element-matching-the-predicate                                                                                                              if my backend does not have o retrieve that field "isNew" my code trow my that exceptions, that's was in my case

Comment: @VivekModi use `firstOrNull` instead of `first` in that case. Then, check that the element is not null to proceed with the list operations.

Comment: I fixed this by using **find**, but i'll try your solutions. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

A trick to do all of this in just one line in Kotlin is with `sortBy`

```
people.sortByDescending { it.lastName == "Forkbeard" }
```