# Room DataBase Implementation not found w/Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack-compose

I have looked around here and other sites, but I can't figure out the solution.

everything worked fine till I initialized the `RoomViewModel.kt` in `MainActivity.kt`.

I keep getting this error

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.caller.fakecaller.data.DataBase. DataBase_Impl does not exist
        at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:97)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:1358)
        at com.caller.fakecaller.data.DataBase$Companion.getInstance(DataBase.kt:31)
        at com.caller.fakecaller.data.RoomViewModel.<init>(RoomViewModel.kt:18)
        at com.caller.fakecaller.util.RoomViewModelFactory.create(RoomViewModelFactory.kt:14)...
```

I have this gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.caller.fakecaller"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.0.2"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.2"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.2"

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0")

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"

    //Navigation with Compose
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha08")

    //Preferences
    implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1")

    //Activity
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0-alpha01'

    //Glide Accompanist
    implementation "dev.chrisbanes.accompanist:accompanist-glide:0.4.2"

}
```

when i added the plugins `kotlin-android` and `kotlin-kapt` it said that they weren't found.
therefore i had to change the app gradle to be like this (based on other posts)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30"
    }
}

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
        }
    }
}
```

but that gave me these errors

```
com/android/build/gradle/BaseExtension
> com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension


Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension'.
```

in the database file I did as follows:

```
private const val DATABASE_NAME = "FakeCaller"


@Database(entities = [Contact::class, RingTone::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class DataBase:RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun UserDao(): UserDao

    abstract fun RingDao():RingDao

//Implementing the DataBase
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: DataBase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): DataBase {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE

                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        DataBase::class.java,
                        DATABASE_NAME
                    ).build()

                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and connected everything to the RoomViewModel (I created a factory for it also)

```
class RoomViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readContactList : LiveData<List<Contact>>
    val readFileUri: LiveData<Uri>
    private val repository : Repository

    init {
        val dbInstance = DataBase.getInstance(application)
        val userDao = dbInstance.UserDao()
        val ringDao = dbInstance.RingDao()
        repository = Repository(userDao, ringDao)
        readContactList = repository.getContacts
        readFileUri = repository.getUri()
    }

    suspend fun getContact(id:Long): LiveData<Contact>{
        return repository.getContact(id)
    }
...
}
```

in MainActivity I made this

```
setContent {
            FakeCallerTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    val context = LocalContext.current
                    val roomViewModel: RoomViewModel = viewModel(
                        factory = RoomViewModelFactory(context.applicationContext as Application)
                    )
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
```

i think there is an issue with the context but i don't know really. still learning...

please help

Comment: Well you can actually use `applicationContext` just like that. Do not invoke LocalContext here since as long as you are within the Activity bounds, you can reference Activity properties just like that.

Comment: i did... same issue

Comment: No that was not the answer it was a suggestion

Comment: I think that the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5), will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49323956/15880865) should help.

Modern day approach:

inside the `plugins` block,

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt' //Add this
}
```

Then, withing `dependencies`,

```
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

Well based on the comment below,

These are all that I have needed to build fine.

```
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

Hey wait, are you connected to the internet? These may need to be downloaded from the web by the studio (downloads automatically). If download does not start, please check whether gradle is configured for offline work. If it is, toggle the state and it will download.

Per the comment below, this seems to have solved the issue

```
project-level-build{
 dependencies{
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha04' 
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
 }
}
```

Comment: i got this: 
Plugin [id: 'kotlin-kapt'] was not found in any of the following sources:
my settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0-alpha10'
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0-alpha10'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.21'
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() ...

Comment: i applied the plugin 'kotlin-android' as well before it. it said the same thing.. not found

Comment: Well there's no problem on my end

Comment: You are doing this in the app level gradle right?

Comment: yes i do have internet and i updated the question above to include both gradles... i guess that the problem is not in the code then?

Comment: what do you have in your both gradles?

Comment: It sounds kinda odd, but could you try removing the runtime depenedency?

Comment: Just add the three I have specified in my answer

Comment: `
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha04'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: These are the only two in my project level build

Comment: man this worked... just update your answer to include the 2 classpaths you have and i will accept it... thank you so much