# How to fix jlink does not exist?

Tags: java, android, react-native, expo, java-11

i am working with `react native` and am trying to use expo in a [bare project](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/exploring-bare-workflow/) but whenever i try to run the app with the command `npm run android`, i get this error :

```
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':expo-modules-core:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /home/dukizwe/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-31/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > jlink executable /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/jlink does not exist.
```

I am using the **linux** OS, **Android studio** and **JDK** are correctly installed.

Inside `/usr/lib/jvm/` folder, the structure look like this:

- java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
- java-1.14.0-openjdk-amd64
- java-11-openjdk-amd64
- java-14-openjdk-amd64
- jdk-18

i don't know why it's looking in the `java-14-openjdk-amd64` folder because in that folder there's no `jlink` executable.

In `android studio` the `SDK Location` si pointed to `java-11-openjdk`. Any help please ?

Comment: If the Java 14 version is not there for you, I expect that you have installed JRE package for Java 14; e.g. `openjdk-14-jre` rather than `openjdk-14-jdk`.   Use `find` to see if can find `jlink` in the `/usr/jvm` tree.

Comment: Looks like somewhere in the project the path of jlink has been specified to be `java-14-openjdk-amd64` folder. You should try searching for this path and correcting it.

Comment: jlink is only available in `java-11-openjdk-amd64` folder. Where exaclty can i change this path in android folder ? I searched everywhere but not find this

Comment: For OpenSuse: `sudo zypper in java-17-openjdk java-17-openjdk-headless java-17-openjdk-devel` (The one missing was -devel). Swap the version 17 with what you need

Answer (score 21):

I also faced same issue when I did run my React Native app on my new Ubuntu 22.x machine. I fixed it with installing JRE along with JDK.

Step 1 `sudo apt install default-jre`  followed by `java -version`

should display -

`Output openjdk version "11.0.14" 2022-01-18 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2, mixed mode, sharing)`

Followed by -
`sudo apt install default-jdk`

Check - `javac -version`  to get output as -

`Output javac 11.0.14`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I'm using JAVA 11.0.19.

Comment: worked for me, thanks a lot! I didn't have a compiler setup, fresh install. New to Java. Much appreciated @pjoshi!

Comment: 4 weeks !! 4 Weeks .... and your response save my life !! THANK YOU

Answer (score 14):

You need to install the development package for Java. On debian, this is the `openjdk-11-jdk` package.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that you need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the parent of the jlink binary. Android Studio includes its own jlink binary. On Linux (or Mac) you can use:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME="$HOME/android-studio/jbr"
```

what comes after `$HOME` would depend on where you have Android Studio installed.

a more permanent solution is to edit your `~/.bashrc` file, append the command provided above (with the path modifications if any) to the end of the said file and save changes. All done, open a new terminal and try compiling again.

On Windows you need to add the JAVA_HOME to your path

Answer (score 5):

For IntelliJ IDEA, go to: `File > Project Structure` and in `Project` tab change `SDK` to any SDK that uses JDK 11 or 8.

Answer (score 3):

I've just copied `jlink`, `javac` and `jmod` from this path:

`/home/USER/android-studio/jre/bin/`

to the following path:

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.15.0.10-1.fc36.x86_64/bin`

Note: It's important to use `Terminal` as root

OS Used: Linux Fedora 36

Comment: Don't copy files like this! You need to install the development package for your Java version (in my case it's Java17 on Fedora 36):
sudo dnf install java-17-openjdk-devel

Comment: thanks i instaled the devel package and it is more pratical

Comment: Am also using Fedora. Most of my mobile projects are Cordova based and I don't have this issue on those, but hit it when I tried a new project out with Capacitor instead. The solution provided by @Tomee worked like a charm. In this instance, since I have to use Java 11 for Cordova on the same development box, Capacitor was trying to use jlink on Java 11, so I went with `sudo dnf install java-11-openjdk-devel`. After that I was able to `npx cap run android`, the point where I was previously getting the jlink does not exist error.

Comment: Confirm this worked for me. Besides jlink I also had to copy a couple of other files. I'm limited to an older Ubuntu machine where installing the openjdk stuff properly was not an option, so this worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

This work for me you can try this out
clean the gradlew then run this command ....

```bash
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless   
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, JDK was missing for Java 17. I installed it using `sudo pacman -Syu jdk17-openjdk`, and it worked.

You probably do not have JDK installed. You can install it from your distro's repository. For Arch Linux, check [this doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/java).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I've installed `java-17-openjdk` on Fedora it turns out that I also need to install `java-17-openjdk-devel`.

```bash
sudo dnf install java-17-openjdk java-17-openjdk-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgrade from Gradle 7 to 8 and I had to also upgrade android Gradle plugin to 8.0.0, My `jvmTarget` was equal to `1.8` and `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` was being used for target and source compatability

But after upgrading to gradle 8, It requires Java version to be atleast 17, I tried setting only source compatability but that didn't work, so I had to change all three, source, target & jvmTarget to 17

My application worked fine on Desktop (jvmMain), But on Android I would get `jlink` executable doesn't exist. Since Its kotlin multiplatform.

What didn't work

- Downloading Coretto 17 and using that
- Removing all sdks in project structure and using only jdk 17 from jbr
- using `jvmToolchain(17)` in kotlin block inside android block
- `invalidateCachesAndRestart` plus deleting the .idea folder

What worked

- Using Android JDK, I removed all jdks in `project structure` -> sdks, Then added android jdk found in the jbr folder of android studio installation
- also selected this jdk in `project structure -> project -> Sdk field`
- You must also change the jdk in `File -> Settings -> BuildTools -> Gradle`

So It appears that the problem is that jbr jdk relly is missing the `jlink` executable since Android Studio jdk is working fine. I am going to redownload the jbr 17 sdk and I am pretty sure it should work , and should contain `jlink` executable, I think during updates somehow `jlink` executable got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In my gradle file I had:

```kotlin
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(8)
    }
```

Setting the same java version for compileOptions and kotlin closures fixed the issue:

```kotlin
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(8)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build react native app using OpenJdk 17 but didnt work. I was getting continuous error as below

```
* What went wrong:
```

Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

```
  > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /home/neeraj/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-33/core-for-system-modules.jar.
     > jlink executable /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.8.0.7-1.fc39.x86_64/bin/jlink does not exist.
```

I installed OpenJdk 11 and this fixed my problem. I have OpenJdk 17 also installed on my machine which I switch as and when needed.

I am using fedora 39.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Manjaro or Archlinux, you have to copy `jlink` from the default-runtime(`/usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime`) to the Java 17 runtime(`/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk`) or your active runtime. You have to be **root** for you to do this. You can run this in your terminal.

`cp /usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime/bin/jlink /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/bin`

You can check your active runtime using `archlinux-java status`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

1. `sudo apt install default-jre`
2. `sudo apt install default-jdk`
3. `java --version`
4. `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
5. `npx react-native run-android && npm start`