# Build Error: 'kspDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17)

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build, kapt

Execution failed for task ':app:kspDebugKotlin'. Unable to build with `ksp`

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kspDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know why it causing problem, but I added this in `gradle(project)` and it worked.

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not work for me

Comment: compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}

try this

Comment: thksssssssssssssss

Answer (score 23):

As well as

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Add (at the same level as android {}):

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(8)
}
```

Comment: I have had to do this with Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 7 to force ksp to continue using jdk 11 - I found this setting from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55947

Answer (score 16):

For those, who still facing issue. Try updating versions of Java and Kotlin to same `17` as follow:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**KSP version must be aligned with your project's Kotlin version.**

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp#add-ksp)

> First, declare the KSP plugin in your top level build.gradle.kts file. Make sure that you choose a KSP version aligned with your project's Kotlin version. You can find a list of releases on the KSP GitHub page.

If you are using Kotlin 1.8.0 ensure to use/downgrade to KPS `1.8.0-1.0.8` because `1.8.0-1.0.9` has a [known bug](https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/1288).

That's how I resolved the issue in my case.

```
// match Kotlin version 1.8.0 and use KPS 1.0.8, not 1.0.9
classpath("com.google.devtools.ksp:com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.plugin:1.8.0-1.0.8")
```

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
```

Comment: Fixed, thank you.  Weird issue, it didn't even happened when using compose with 17

Answer (score 7):

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KaptGenerateStubs).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this one worked for me, `KaptGenerateStubs` was also required

Answer (score 2):

To make sure @deive's solution works, you need JDK 1.8 downloaded also (You can do this by navigating to File -> Project Structure -> Java Options -> Download JDK). If you don't have JDK 1.8 installed, then the Gradle Kotlin DSL will keep throwing errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you got a similar problem with kapt instead of ksp, then copy this in your gradle kts file after android{} block

```
tasks.withType(type = KaptGenerateStubsTask::class) {
kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was KSP version not compatible with kotlin version 2.0.0-Beta4. I am using kotlin version 1.9.22 (as recommended) and KSP version 1.9.22-1.0.17. I hope this helps.

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "$kotlin_version" apply false
id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version "$ksp_version" apply false
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used, It works

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(8))
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(8)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me:

in your project level build.gradle add this at the end:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate{
        tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {
            if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application") || project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
                kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility
            } else {
                kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = sourceCompatibility
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is error is coming after applying Android Studio Flamingo patch 2. But the above workaround worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue using the Android Studio settings recommendation on the Android Developer site to "Set the JDK Version"
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk

For whatever reason, I had Gradle JDK option set to 18.  After selecting Embedded JDK from the options, I was able to build the project.  I hope this helps someone.

From the link above:

> A copy of the latest OpenJDK comes bundled with current versions
> Android Studio, and this is the JDK version we recommend you use for
> your Android projects. To use the bundled JDK, do the following:
>
> 1. Open your project in Android Studio and select File > Settings (on
>    macOS, Android Studio > Preferences).
> 2. In the left pane, navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle.
> 3. Under Gradle JDK, choose the Embedded JDK option.
> 4. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

your current kotlin version is not compatible so update org.jetbrains.kotlin.android plugin version in porject-level build.gradle

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).