# How to resolve the Gradle Build Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to build my project but every time I get the following errors:

###### Error 1

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'kotlin.sequences.Sequence com.google.devtools.ksp.processing.Resolver.getPackagesWithAnnotation(java.lang.String)'
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspRoundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(KspRoundEnv.kt:107)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.CommonProcessorDelegate.processRound(XBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:100)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspBasicAnnotationProcessor.process(KspBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:62)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension$doAnalysis$6$1.invoke(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:291)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension$doAnalysis$6$1.invoke(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:289)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.handleException(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:394)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.doAnalysis(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:289)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:257)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:248)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

###### Error 2

```
Execution failed for task ':core:database:kspDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

###### File Contents

This is my project level build.gradle.kts file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
}
```

This is my module level build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.yangian.superclock.core.database"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 28

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")
//    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-guava:1.7.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.9.10")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.7.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:core:1.5.0")

    // Room
    val roomVersion = "2.6.0"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

    // Dagger Hilt
    val daggerVersion = "2.48"

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$daggerVersion")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$daggerVersion")
}
```

I am new to Android Development and the gradle errors always scares me. I tried to get help from Bard and Bing but nothing worked. So, you guys are my last resort. Please help me to resolve these errors. Feel free to ask  for more information about the project in order to resolve the error.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, try downgrading your hilt to 2.48, also I would recommend keeping the Hilt Plugin and the dependency in the same version.




id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false

implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48")

Comment: @ibrhm117 thanks for your recommendations, I have downgraded the version to `2.48` in both the plugin as well as the dependency. But the issue still persist. I believe the issue has something to do with the `ksp`.

Comment: I was also facing exact same issue as yours, I downgraded `room` to last stable version i.e. `2.5.2` which solved the issue for me. There seems to be some issue in latest version `2.6.0`

Comment: Thanks @DanishAnsari your method worked for me. Earlier it was gaving some message like `Internal Compiler Error`. But after I changed the `room` version to `2.5.2`, it provided me the logs of actual bug that was there in the file.

Comment: There is a comment in the issuetracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303703303#comment3. KSP, which means Kotlin and also implies Dagger (due to metadata), has to be updated.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I have a feeling (haven't dug too deep into it yet) that Dagger/Hilt version `2.48` are not compatible with somewhat outdated versions of Kotlin language (which is what you seem to be having, based on the content of your Gradle files).

You might need to bump

- `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` to `1.9.10`;
- `com.google.devtools.ksp` to `1.9.10-1.0.13`;

You can keep Dagger/Hilt set to `2.48.1` and Room set to `2.6.0`.

I just upgraded Room to `2.6.0` in the project I work on and these are the versions that I ended up having. Works like a charm, the exception that you mentioned is gone.

**Upd.** Yep, there is actually a [discussion](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303703303#comment3) of that same issue on Google's issue tracker; the latest versions of Kotlin and KSP are required to use Room 2.6.0.

Answer (score 6):

update kotlin to 1.9.10

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.3'
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.10' apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13" apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the order of plugins as such

Module-level build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}
```

App level build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.3.15" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
}
```

I ran into the same issue you're mentioning while updating to hilt 2.48.1, downgrading was the only way I was able to resolve this.

Also as [hata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501958/hata) pointed out remove the id("com.android.library") from your module-level build.gradle.kts.

Comment: I tried what you and hata suggested but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hilt has a [bug](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3965#issuecomment-1662360344).

The key issue to solving it is to declare the `ksp` plugin in the root `build.gradle` and not apply it.

Full working configuration.

#### Root build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48.1" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version("1.9.10-1.0.13") apply false
}
```

#### App module build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") // <------------- without version
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}
```