"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in KSP with Dagger Hilt and Room"
I am working on an Android project using Kotlin 1.9.10, Dagger Hilt 2.52, and KSP 1.9.10-1.0.13. During the build, I encountered the following error:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'kotlin.KotlinVersion com.google.devtools.ksp.processing.SymbolProcessorEnvironment.getKspVersion()'
    at dagger.spi.internal.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspStarTypeArgumentType.<init>(KspStarTypeArgumentType.kt:43)
    at dagger.spi.internal.shaded.androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspProcessingEnv.wrap(KspProcessingEnv.kt:281)
    ...

Here are the details of my setup:

Android Gradle Plugin version: 8.1.2
Kotlin version: 1.9.10
KSP version: 1.9.10-1.0.13
Hilt version: 2.52
Android compile SDK version: 34
minSdk: 25
targetSdk: 34
Java version: 19
Compose Compiler version: 1.5.1
Room version: 2.6.1

implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.52")
ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.52")

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.10-1.0.13" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.52" apply false
}

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, but the error persists. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Have you tried looking at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77342860/how-to-resolve-the-gradle-build-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror

As indicated in the release notes for Dagger 2.52:

Notes:
Dagger KSP now requires at least KSP 1.9.24-1.0.20.

The error also hints as to a cause, being what @AnishB mentioned (a commit to introduce kspVersion):

Introduce SymbolProcessorEnvironment.kspVersion
To be consistent with apiVersion, only major.minor is used. patch is ignored.
TODO: automatically update after KSP 1 is deprecated.

This commit was first added into release 1.9.23-1.0.19:


You'll have to bump your Kotlin and KSP versions accordingly:
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.24" apply false
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.24-1.0.20" apply false

You might also want to consider updating your project to use Kotlin 2.0+ to benefit from improved compile times as well as other improvements.
