# Unable to find Room Database implementation in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am encountering an issue with Room Database in my Android Kotlin application. When attempting to run the application, I'm getting the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.miauto/com.example.miauto.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find` 
implementation for com.example.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
Here's a simplified version of my code related to Room Database:

```
build.gradle.kts:

val room_version = "2.5.0"

implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
// ... (other dependencies)
```

```
LoginActivity.kt:

// ... (imports)

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // ...

        val vehiculos = listOf(
            // ... (list of vehicles)
        )

        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "vehiculos"
        ).build()

        val vehiculoDao = db.vehiculoDao()

        for (vehiculo in vehiculos) {
            vehiculoDao.InsertarVehiculo(vehiculo)
        }

        val todosLosVehiculos = vehiculoDao.ObtenerVehiculos()

        for (vehiculo in todosLosVehiculos) {
            println("ID: ${vehiculo.id}, Marca: ${vehiculo.marca}, Modelo: ${vehiculo.modelo}, Tipo: ${vehiculo.tipo}")
        }
    }
}
```

```
AppDatabase.kt:


// ... (imports)

@Database(entities = [Vehiculo::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun vehiculoDao(): DAOvehiculo
}
```

```
DAOvehiculo.kt:

// ... (imports)

@Dao
interface DAOvehiculo {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM vehiculo")
    fun ObtenerVehiculos(): List<Vehiculo>

    @Insert
    fun InsertarVehiculo(vehiculo: Vehiculo)
}
```

I've added the necessary dependencies for Room in my build.gradle.kts, and I have the required entities, database, and DAO set up. However, I'm still encountering the error mentioned above. Any insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

This is mi logcat:

`2023-12-10 18:51:16.432 17503-17503 AndroidRuntime          com.example.miauto                   D  Shutting down VM 2023-12-10 18:51:16.437 17503-17503 AndroidRuntime          com.example.miauto                   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.miauto, PID: 17503 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.miauto/com.example.miauto.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.kt:58) at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.kt:1351) at com.example.miauto.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.kt:56) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android room persistent: AppDatabase\_Impl does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665621/android-room-persistent-appdatabase-impl-does-not-exist)

Comment: I add this to my files:

ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

id("com.google.devtools.ksp")

And got this error:

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/mpp/pm20/KotlinCompilationData

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

try changing annotationProcessor to kapt in the apps build.gradle

for example:

```
// Extensions = ViewModel + LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
// Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

**also remember to add this plugin**

> apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

Comment: Since Octuber 2023 there is a update where kapt pass to ksp:
https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp?hl=en

Y tried but i got a error:
Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.pm20.KotlinCompilationData'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.

Comment: change build.gradle classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0' and distributionUrl distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip . i think problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

I fix it changing to the lastest version of ksp: 1.9.21-1.0.15

For the future check this page for the exact version:

https://github.com/google/ksp/releases