Room.kt - Database_Impl does not exist
I am trying to implement Database in a fresh app, but for some reason it's crashing and after a lot of searches I am posting this issue, I did not find anything relevant:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
    Process: com.basic.app, PID: 19092
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.basic.app.data.MyDatabase. MyDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.kt:58)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.kt:1351)
        at com.basic.app.data.DatabaseProvider.getDatabase(DatabaseProvider.kt:18)
        at com.basic.app.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:44)
        at com.basic.app.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:36)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:117)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
        at androidx.compose.material3.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1$bodyContentPlaceables$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:239)
        at androidx.compose.material3.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1$bodyContentPlaceables$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:221)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$3$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:1067)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$3$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:701)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3340)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3273)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:588)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1013)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:4007)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:520)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:721)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:694)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:685)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:669)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:1014)
        at androidx.compose.material3.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:221)
        at androidx.compose.material3.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:128)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1$measure$1.placeChildren(SubcomposeLayout.kt:879)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:365)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:357)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2299)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:467)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:83)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.layoutChildren(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:357)

Here is my main activity code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var database: MyDatabase
    private lateinit var activityRepository: ActivityRepository

    @SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            WalkathonTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                            name = "Android",
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )

                    if (!::database.isInitialized) {
                        database = DatabaseProvider.getDatabase(this)
                    }

                    // Initialize activityRepository if not already initialized
                    if (!::activityRepository.isInitialized) {
                        database.let { db ->
                            activityRepository = ActivityRepository(db.activityDao())
                        }
                    }

                    // Fetch all activities asynchronously
                    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        val activities = activityRepository.all()
                        // Loop through the activities
                        for (activity in activities) {
                            // Perform operations with each activity
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "Activity: $activity")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    WalkathonTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}

Here is my Dao:
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Update

@Dao
interface ActivityDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(activity: ActivityModel)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(activity: ActivityModel)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(activity: ActivityModel)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM activity")
    suspend fun all(): List<ActivityModel>
}

Here is my model:
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.util.Date

@Entity(tableName = "activity")
data class ActivityModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val steps: Int,
    val createdAt: Date,
    val updatedAt: Date? = null
)

Here is my repository:
class ActivityRepository(private val activityDao: ActivityDao) {
    suspend fun all(): List<ActivityModel> {
        return activityDao.all()
    }
}

Here is my Database:
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [ActivityModel::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun activityDao(): ActivityDao
}

Here is my DatabaseProvider:
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room

object DatabaseProvider {

    private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null

    fun getDatabase(context: Context): MyDatabase {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MyDatabase::class.java,
                    context.getString(R.string.database_name)
                ).build()
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }
}

Here is my gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.basic.app"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.basic.app"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.common)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

Version catalog:
[versions]
agp = "8.4.1"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.10.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.6.1"
activityCompose = "1.8.0"
composeBom = "2023.08.00"
roomCommon = "2.6.1"
roomCompiler = "2.6.1"
roomKtx = "2.6.1"
roomRuntime = "2.6.1"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomCompiler" }
androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
androidx-room-common = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-common", version.ref = "roomCommon" }
androidx-room-ktx = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "roomKtx" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }

I wanted to run the app successfully, but it's crashing.

can you also include the imports for the entity and the database? It may be you've imported something wrong

also, just as a tip, do not do setAlarmReceiver(this) nor the if statements checking if something is initialized in the composable scope, those will be run on every recomposition, wrap them in LaunchedEffects or move them outside composable scope

Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665621/android-room-persistent-appdatabase-impl-does-not-exist/77844106#77844106

@JustSightseeing please check the code now.

if you also include your version catalog I will copy the project and solve it

Without further testing, but maybe this is caused by the name of your database class Database: It might be conflicting with the @Database annotation. Try renaming your database class to MyDatabase or whatever you like.

@Leviathan, updated and tested with MyDatabase name, it's still showing same error

The base error is MyDatabase_Impl does not exist, how is the app compiling if a class is missing?

Actually @Majedul Islam was correct, just failed to show how to add the dependency correctly:
in build.gradle to plugin block add:kotlin("kapt")
like so:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    kotlin("kapt")
}

then in dependencies add kapt(libs.androidx.room.compiler) as you were missing only this one
in the end make sure all 3 of those dependencies are there (don't add all 3 as you had some of them)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.common)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    kapt(libs.androidx.room.compiler)

and it fixes your problem, however it will still not build since you're using a Date in your entity (and that requires a type converter)
so create a class Converter
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
        return value?.let { Date(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time?.toLong()
    }
}

and in your database add: @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
so it looks like this:
@Database(entities = [ActivityModel::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class Database : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun activityDao(): ActivityDao
}

