# Unable to merge dex - gradle 3.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, dex, android-room

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to work though this tutorial (just the Room database part): [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-livedata-and-viewmodel-fca5da39e26b).

When I execute my app I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. `>` com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

This issue seemed to show up after I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322178/room-schema-export-directory-is-not-provided-to-the-annotation-processor-so-we) to fix another error (regarding the schema export directory for Room). I've tried to follow [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex) advice about fixing this issue by using `multiDexEnabled true` and doing clean/re-build but it hasn't worked.

Any advice would be appreciated. This is my first post here so if I've done anything wrong please let me know.

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
    supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
    archRoomVersion = "1.0.0-alpha1"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } //needed for Room

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myname.room_example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()] // Room schema
            }
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0'
}
```

Comment: `buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"` & `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`

Answer (score 0):

Update `buildToolsVersion` and `supportLibVersion` to the latest in your code below.

```
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
supportLibVersion = "25.3.1"
archRoomVersion = "1.0.0-alpha1"
```

}

And then Clean and Rebuild Project to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately this hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Replacing:

```
"android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

and

```
"android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

with

```
"android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
```

and

```
"android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```