# Cannot find GlideApp after adding the Room compiler

Tags: android, android-room, android-glide

compile project failed with error "cannot find symbol class GlideApp" after added room components to the gradle config file. Project compile without error if comment out "annotation processor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version". Any ideas?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.otpuskarche.onleave"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "1.1.1"
    def archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

    // Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: remove `**`  before and after `**annotationProcessor`

Comment: sorry, but posted wrong config at first with **. The issue is somewhere else :(

Comment: did u add glide module ?

Comment: yes, I did, but if I remove annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version" project builds ok! It looks like a conflict between glide and room.

Comment: I am using both together in kotlin but i don't have any error

Comment: which version? 
glide:4.7.1
room:1.1.1

Comment: room 1.1.1 , Glide is 4.7.1 but glide compiler is 4.6.1

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with room. The schema export directory was not set. Build log feint me as the error appeared on the bottom of the log.

reference to real issue - [room-schema-export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322178/room-schema-export-directory-is-not-provided-to-the-annotation-processor-so-we)

Answer (score 1):

Create a call like

```
@GlideModule
public final class GlideLoader extends AppGlideModule{


 }
```

And Build Project.Then You will access glide by GlideApp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the annotationProcessor dependency:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
```

You also need to add an [AppGlideModule](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/module/AppGlideModule.html). See the [generated API documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1939) for details.