# Expected @HiltAndroidApp to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I have Google this problem, but the results are not work for me.

The detail as following.

```java
    public final class App extends com.zhixin.wedeep.common.BaseApplication implements androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner {
                 ^
     // Expected @HiltAndroidApp to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin?
```

The App code.

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : BaseApplication(), LifecycleOwner {

    @Inject
    lateinit var service: EventService


    private val mLifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)

}
```

This module gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

dependencies {
    implementation rootProject.ext.dependencies["hilt-android"]
    implementation rootProject.ext.dependencies["hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel"]
    kapt rootProject.ext.kapt["hilt-compiler"]
    kapt rootProject.ext.kapt["hilt-android-compiler"]
}
```

Who has ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This issue also appears after upgrading Kotlin to 1.5.20 (https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2684) Adding `kapt.use.worker.api=false` in `gradle.properties` solves the problem.

Comment: Fixed by Kotlin 1.5.21

Comment: Is not fixed after upgrading kotlin to `1.5.21`

Comment: the flag kapt.use.worker.api=false solved my problem. Thanks to share it!

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I just hit this problem this morning.  Do you have anything in your build.gradle that adds arguments to the annotationProcessOptions?  For example:

```
  android {
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                                 "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If so, try changing from "arguments =" to "arguments +=", as just using equals overwrites anything set previously.

Comment: This work for me, because i dont add ```   annotationProcessorOptions {
                    arguments += ["room.schemaLocation":
                                 "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
                }``` to my module build.gradle file. Documents don't give any prompt that above codes should be added to build.gradle if using ```Room```.

Comment: for Kotlin DLS it could be :
`arguments = arguments + mapOf("room.incremental" to "true")`

Comment: one can also use this syntax `arguments["room.schemaLocation"] = ... arguments["room.incremental"] = true` to add as many arguments as they want, but with the above answer, this is most prolly not needed

Comment: Thank you, it does say this in the [docs](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup) but I skimmed it completely

Comment: Nice! Just ran into this now and I don't think I ever would have guess this was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

EDIT: Looks like kotlin gradle plugin 1.5.21 solves the problem without using the bellow javacOptions.
UPDATE Kotlin and try again!

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
```

If you are not using Room and still get the error put this in the android block of build.gradle:

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        // These options are normally set automatically via the Hilt Gradle plugin, but we
        // set them manually to workaround a bug in the Kotlin 1.5.20
        option("-Adagger.fastInit=ENABLED")
        option("-Adagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation=true")
    }
}
```

It's a kapt bug on kotlin 1.5.20: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2684

Comment: thank you. it solved my problem.

Answer (score 32):

#### SOLUTION 1 : Downgrade kotlin

If you are using `kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20` (in your project level `build.gradle`), downgrading it to `1.5.10` should fix the issue.
The issue will probably be fixed in the next versions, then you will upgrade to the new version.

#### SOLUTION 2 : Disable Gradle worker API

Add this line to your `gradle.properties` file:

`kapt.use.worker.api=false`

It will disable the [gradle worker API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/worker_api.html).
It works for me, but as said in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#running-kapt-tasks-in-parallel):

> Using the worker API lets Gradle run independent annotation processing tasks from a single project in parallel, which in some cases significantly decreases the execution time.

So by disabling it, your build may be slowed down.

Comment: Downgrading kotlin was the solution for me thanks

Comment: Solution2 works for me :)

Comment: yeah solution 2 works for me too.

Answer (score 13):

Just don't forget to add **Hilt classpath dependency** to your project level gradle file:

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$versions.daggerHiltCoreVersion"
```

Define the specific version number instead of *$versions.daggerHiltCoreVersion* above.

And add plugin to your app level gradle:

`apply plugin : 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'`

For later Gradle versions, add the plugin as follows

```
plugins {
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to sitatech's answer, I've also encountered this issue using `kotlin-grade-plugin-1.5.20`. The new `1.5.21` patch solved it for me.

Kotlin Grade Plugin v1.5.21 release notes: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.5.21

Issue in Jetbrains issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47416

Answer (score 3):

To backup @SteveC answer, when using Kotlin Gradle DSL is a bit different

We can't use either `+=` or `arguments = mapOf()`. As stated in the official Dagger-Hilt [documentation here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html#applying-other-processor-arguments) & the [github issue here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1902#issuecomment-642623086) regarding the docs as well

See below image for explanations:

[image: arguments = mapOf()]

1. `arguments = mapOf()` will call `setArguments` with `this.arguments.clear()`, thus will overwrite previous argument (in this case `Hilt`)

Workaround approach:

```
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments(
                    mapOf(
                        "dagger.gradle.incremental" to "true",
                        "room.incremental" to "true"
                    )
                )
            }
        }
```

Wrapping the `arguments()` as a functions instead of calling setter, it'll retain the previous `arguments` as well.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, `multi module` in `presentaion` layer, I just removed :

```
javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                                 "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
                }
            }
        }
```

in `defaultConfig` block