# Dagger-Hilt Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? But I applied the plugin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

Hello I'm trying to use the Dagger Hilt library In my project but when I'm trying to build it, it fails with this message

```
public final class MyApplication extends android. app.Application {
             ^
  Expected @HiltAndroidApp to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? (dagger.hilt.android.plugin)
  See https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See the error above for details.
```

And then a java file called MyApplication.java opens with the below content:

```
package com.example.hilt;

import android.app.Application;
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp;
import kotlin.reflect.KClass;

@kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 5, 1}, k = 1, d1 = {"\u0000\f\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\b\u0002\b\u0007\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002\u00a8\u0006\u0003"}, d2 = {"Lcom/example/hilt/MyApplication;", "Landroid/app/Application;", "()V", "app_debug"})
@dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp
public final class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {
    
    public MyApplication() {
        super();
    }
}
```

this is my project `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.20"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.37'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my app module `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hilt"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.37"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

as you see I did everything correctly and it still gives me the error. I tested my code on another computer and it worked! I even removed android studio, Gradle, and SDK manager from my computer and reinstall them but it still gives me the error.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Here you can see an issue related to support for Kotlin's plugin 1.5.20 and as it explains this is the bug of Kotlin's plugin, not dagger hilt's!

The solution is simple, you have to add this code to your build.gradle app module:

```
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        option("-Adagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation=true")
    }
}
```

Edit:

Just update the Kotlin plugin to the latest version and change `ext.kotlin_version` to the latest version in project-level build.gradle. The current version is `1.5.21`.

Comment: This is not the solution. I expect kotlin-plugin developers to fix the issue

Comment: updating kotlin version fixed the issue for me
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"

Answer (score 1):

you did not add annotationProcessor check following link https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html

add like this in your app.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.37'
```

Comment: I'm using it with Kotlin and I don't need the annotationProcessor.

Comment: yes if you check android studio they referring to your sample which maybe solve your problem did you apply my answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887817/expected-hiltandroidapp-to-have-a-value-did-you-forget-to-apply-the-gradle-plu check this answer as well

Comment: Yes, I almost checked all topics with a similar error and any of them didn't solve the error.

Comment: invalidate cache restart maybe it will help

Comment: I found the solution, it was Kotlin version 1.5.20 bug!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the version of this below classpath in your project level gradle to the latest version -

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:VERSION_TO_CHANGE"
```

Comment: Thanks! In edit section of the correct answer I also said it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on fresh project. And problem was in wrong gradle path.

I specified in `local.properties` this:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Users/cmx/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7935034/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
```

And it helps me.