# Dagger Hilt Error: @HiltAndroidApp to have a value. Did you forget to apply Gradle Plugin?(dagger.hilt.android.plugin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

Getting this
error: [Hilt]
public final class BaseApplication extends android.app.Application {
^
Expected @HiltAndroidApp to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? (dagger.hilt.android.plugin)

@HiltAndroidApp
public class BaseApplication:Application() {

}

Along with this error I am also getting this error
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887817/expected-hiltandroidapp-to-have-a-value-did-you-forget-to-apply-the-gradle-plu

Comment: Already did this solution but it didn't work

Comment: Adding kapt.use.worker.api=false in gradle.properties solves the problem.

Comment: quick tip : put your code in code fences to make it easier to read