# Type mismatch: inferred type is AutoMigration but KClass<*> was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I was trying to implement a simple auto migration that just adds a nullable string field to my only table, but for some reason I am getting the following error in the  `autoMigrations = [AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 2)]` line:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is AutoMigration but KClass<*> was expected

I say that this is a weird error, because even the [documentation has it this way.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions)

The full code is below:

```
@Database(
    version = 2,
    entities = [Note::class],
    autoMigrations = [AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 2)]
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class NotesDB : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun noteDao(): NoteDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: NotesDB? = null

        fun getDB(context: Context): NotesDB {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    NotesDB::class.java,
                    "notesDB"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is is useful, I am also getting another error in the same line that I think is related to the first one: Database.autoMigrations can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.room)

Comment: Considering that I'm getting the same error and this error has led me just to this page, I be leave it might be a new bug or there should be some other requirements that we are not satisfying...

Comment: @AKTanara I had to use a manual migration instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change room version in your build.gradle to the newest one (2.4.0-alpha04 at the moment). Then if you will get an error about room.schemaLocation, look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424908/6568162

Comment: Worked after changing the room dependency version to `2.4.0-alpha04`

Answer (score 0):

set up `export schema = true`.

It is possible you will still get the error, In my case downgrading the room version and again upgrading helped.