# Kapt to KSP migration errors

Tags: android, kotlin, kapt, kotlin-symbol-processing

I am getting an error message when I try to migrate an android project using `kapt` to `KSP`.

Error message

```
Unable to find method ''void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions)''
'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions)'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Currently, the following libraries are using `kapt`.

1. Moshi
2. Hilt
3. Room

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
    id "com.google.devtools.ksp" version "1.6.10-1.0.4"
}

dependencies {

    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$rootProject.hiltVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$rootProject.hiltVersion"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$rootProject.hiltLifecycleViewModelVersion"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$rootProject.hiltCompilerVersion"

    // KSP
    // implementation "com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:1.6.10-1.0.4"

    // Moshi
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$rootProject.moshiVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$rootProject.moshiKotlinVersion"
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$rootProject.moshiKotlinCodegenVersion"
    // ksp "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
}
```

For more details,
The repo is hosted here - https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/finance-manager

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, I am using the following libraries that are using `kapt`.

1. Moshi
2. Hilt
3. Room

---

From the [KSP Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html#supported-libraries), I found out `Hilt` is not yet supported. (as of 25-06-2022).

So, I would need to use both `kapt` and `hilt` in my project.

---

The following `build.gradle` does that,

```
plugins {
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
    id "com.google.devtools.ksp" version "1.6.21-1.0.6"
}

// Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$rootProject.hiltVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$rootProject.hiltVersion"
//ksp "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$rootProject.hiltVersion"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$rootProject.hiltLifecycleViewModelVersion"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$rootProject.hiltCompilerVersion"
// ksp "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$rootProject.hiltCompilerVersion"

// KSP
implementation "com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:1.6.21-1.0.6"

// Moshi
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$rootProject.moshiVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$rootProject.moshiKotlinVersion"
// kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$rootProject.moshiKotlinCodegenVersion"
ksp "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0"preferences:$rootProject.datastorePreferencesVersion"

// Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
// kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
```

**Library versions**

```
roomVersion = "2.5.0-alpha02"
moshiVersion = "1.13.0"
hiltVersion = "2.42"
hiltPluginVersion = "2.40.1"
hiltLifecycleViewModelVersion = "1.0.0-alpha03"
hiltCompilerVersion = "1.0.0"
```

---

Also encountered this error - [Room - Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44322178/9636037)

And this solution helped - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71451314/9636037

```
ksp {
    arg('room.schemaLocation', "$projectDir/schemas")
}
```

Comment: UPD: KSP alpha-support released in Dagger/Hilt 2.48.

Comment: @Abhimanyu But how to config it when I'm using Gradle Catalogs?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, It seems that hilt is not supporting KSP yet, so include it in your gradle file

```
plugin {
    ...
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    ...
}
```

and replace

```
 ksp 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'
```

with

```
 kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'
```

It worked in my case :)

Answer (score 1):

Only dagger version 2.48 or above is supported by ksp according to the dagger doc https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/ksp.